# Max of a Table with a Function

Tags: mathematical-optimization

I want to find the maximum of a function (f) over a variable (t). The function is huge and it's not possible to maximize f(t) directly. So I want to create f inside a Table and then find the highest value over a small range of t. How can I add the steps to construct f into a Table? It seems "/."  is not working.

A simplified version of my problem is:

```
   v = Table[f = TR1 + TR2 
      /.  TR1 = Solve[TR1 - t = 0, {TR1}]
       /. TR2 = t + 1
   , {t, 1, 3, 1}];

  tstar = Max[v]
```

f(t) has many components like TR1 and TR2 which makes it so huge.

Answer (score 1):

You don't actually need to create a variable called `f` in each element of the table; just return the value you need. You also want rules, rather than assignments. Try

```
v = Table[ TR1 + TR2 /. Flatten[{
        Solve[TR1 - t == 0, TR1],
        TR2 -> t + 1}],
      {t, 1, 3, 1}];

tstar = Max[v]
```

Note that `Solve[...]` actually returns a list of substitutions for `TR1`, so we've simply flattened it with the `TR2` rule.

Answer (score 0):

The code contains numerous syntax errors.  It could, for instance, be written as

```
v = Table[(TR1 + TR2) /. Flatten@Solve[TR1 - t == 0, TR1] /. TR2 -> t + 1, {t, 1, 3, 1}]
tstar = Max[v]

(* {3, 5, 7} *)
(* 7 *)
```